# Ionic BLE ble.write return null on ios

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using this plugin inside a ionic + stencil app
https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

I'm send a write command to a characteristic that support WRITE.
If I call ble.write on Android, the callback returns me OK
If I call ble.write on iOS, the callback returns me NULL.
in both cases, I can see on my peripheral device that the command has been sent correctly.

I connect to the device like this:

```
  connectToDevice(device){
var toast = new utils();
let tclass;
let tmessage;

console.log('----connectToDevice----');
BLE.connect(device.id).subscribe( 
    peripheralData => {
      this.device = peripheralData;
      let connectBtn = document.querySelector('#connectBtn') as any;
      console.log('device connected: ', this.device);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('connect error: ', error);
    }
);
```

}

And then, send the command with this code:

```
async sendCommandNew(id){
    let noteOk;
    let noteError;

    let data;
    data = this.stringToBytes(this.commandToSend);
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {
      BLE.write(id, "49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455", "49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616", data).then((res) => {
        console.log('res: ', res);
       
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('res no');
      }
      )
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); console.log('stopped'); }, 5000);
  }
```

This is the characteristic

[image]

Inside the plugin issue many people had this problem but no solution provided.

Comment: The plugin you are using did not receive an update in a while. There might have been some changes which did not find their way into the plugin. Have a look at https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle it seems to be more up to date

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I didn't used this plugin because as the doc says: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#limitations--issues
OS X is still experimental. I'm experiencing some problems, but may be related to Cordova itself.

and I need that the ble works bot on ios and android.

Comment: You are right. I'm not that familiar with apples naming convention, I just assumed the requirement for iOS 10 or higher would mean that iOS works. Maybe someone else is able to help you!